# CodeIgniter: Call to a member function WriteHTML() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

I am getting this error when I an downloading a pdf file using MPDF. I am loading the code here below:

```
    $html = $this->load->view('customer/case_report',$this->data, true);
    $pdfFilePath = "output_pdf_name.pdf";
    $this->load->library('M_pdf');
    $this->M_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $this->M_pdf->pdf->Output('CaseReport_CaseNo_'.$caseNo.'.pdf', 'D');
```

**UPDATE**
Attaching screenshot here:
[image: The WriteHTML code in on line number 34]

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: $pdfFilePath = 'CaseReport_CaseNo_'.$caseNo.'.pdf'; and then try $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will check

Comment: It's still throwing the same error

Comment: can you share error screenshot

Comment: ok let me simulate it on my machine

Answer (score 2):

Alright I have Simulated the case and what Worked is as follows

Downloaded Library from [mPDF Library using Codeigniter](https://github.com/phpclicks/mpdf)

Placed it in application/third_party. Created a File M_pdf.php in application/libraries

```
<?php
  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
  include_once APPPATH.'/third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php';

  class M_pdf {

    public $param;
    public $pdf;
    public function __construct($param = "'c', 'A4-L'")
    {
      $this->param =$param;
      $this->pdf = new mPDF($this->param);
    }
 }
?>
```

Created a Test function in My Controller to test. At first I was trying to save it and getting an error like

[image: Error]

But then I replace the F switch in Output with D for download

```
public function mdfTest()
{
  $pdfFilePath = time()."_order.pdf";
  $this->load->library('M_pdf');
  $html="<html><h1>This is test pdf</h1></html>";
  $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);

  //download it.
  $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");

}
```

And it worked. Created a PDF file like

[image: PDF File created by mPDF]

Comment: I'll give it a shot and let you know

Comment: It worked I just downloaded the latest version of mpdf and added the above file you mentioned. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

File Name : libraries/M_pdf.php 
Folder Name : third_party/mpdf

include_once APPPATH.'/third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php';

class M_pdf {

```
public $param;
public $pdf;

public function __construct($param = '"en-GB-x","A4","","",10,10,10,10,6,3')
{
    $this->param =$param;
    $this->pdf = new mPDF($this->param);
}
```

}

Controller File

```
    public function pdf_create()
    {
        $this->load->library('M_pdf');
        $pdffile = time()."_order.pdf";
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML("My First Codeigniter in First Pdf 
        Create.");
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdffile, "I");
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eplfX.png

Comment: Please edit your answer with the output as plain text, not an image.